# Spring Oauth 2.3.8 clashes with Spring security 5.4.6

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using a spring security in my app. I need it to secure two api's endpoints. Here is security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val authProps: AuthenticationProperties
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(encoder)
            .withUser(authProps.user)
            .password(encoder.encode(authProps.password))
            .roles("USER")
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/firstapi/**", "/secondapi/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
    }
}
```

Also, i'm integrating with an external service, that uses oauth2, here it's restTemplate config -

```
@Configuration
class ExternalServiceConfiguration {

@Bean("externalProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("http.external.api")
fun externalHttpClientConfig() = HttpClientProperties()

@Bean("externalDetails")
@ConfigurationProperties("http.external.api.security.oauth2")
fun externalOAuth2Details() = ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails()

@Bean("externalRestTemplate")
fun externalClientRestTemplate(
    @Qualifier("externalProperties") externalHttpClientProperties: HttpClientProperties,
    @Qualifier("externalDetails") externalOAuth2Details: ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails,
    customizerProviders: ObjectProvider<RestTemplateCustomizer>,
    objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
): RestTemplate {
    val template = OAuth2RestTemplate(externalOAuth2Details).apply {
        messageConverters = listOf(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper))
        requestFactory = requestFactory(externalHttpClientProperties)
        errorHandler = IntegrationResponseErrorHandler()
    }
        customizerProviders.orderedStream().forEach { it.customize(template) }
        return template
    }
}
```

Somehow spring-security-oauth clashes with spring-security. When i try to obtain a token i'm failing at lib class method:

```
AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(...)
```

, because instead of null i have an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` authentication at context, when it calls

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

So spring security merges anonymous context somehow, i am not sure when and how, so that it affects external calls.

Could anyone help me with advice, how can i find the collision???

Comment: When i disable web security (comment @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity) oauth restTemplate works great

Comment: Can you provide your maven/gradle dependencies or build file?

Comment: i use spring-boot:2.4.5 and such security dependencids:
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.8.RELEASE")